# generating a specific chart in ssrs

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I'm using business intelligence development studio, and I'm trying to generate a chart as shown below in SSRS. A chart with multiple series in each dataset. and multiple dataset in the graph. Each group of data in Dataset reference to purple at 100%.

Is there anyway i can acheieve this?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anyway i can acheieve this?

Yes, mostly. ( Have you tried? Where did you run into problems? I'll take a guess at what the problems were.)

The part that will be close to impossible will be the arrow graphics, but you could put some text such as "<-- Better   Worse -->" instead, on blank transparent bars if needed. Alternately you might be able to place arrows on a custom background graphic and size that appropriately. Or use a green to red gradient background graphic instead.

The coloring a single grid line is accomplished by using a strip line. There are a few different blog entries around on adding these, and Technet has some [info](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239316%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: using line strips is seems easy, but I tried to used different templates for the chart, and I'm not really sure which template i can use to replicated this chart with the feature of comparing the value on the percentage of each dataset based on a base value(in this figure, purple). Some of my dataset had huge difference in value. for example. A1= 25000, A2= 25500, A3=26000, B1=130,B2=135,B3=140. if i simple display them based on their values, it's hard to make comparision visually.

Comment: I would calculate the percentages in your dataset, and add those as additional columns / fields. This could either be in the SQL query, or as calculated fields of the dataset.